# What are the lines in the Bhagavad Gita that Sandip is alluding to?

Tags: quote-source, rabindranath-tagore, bengali-language, sanskrit-language, mahabharata

Rabindranath Tagore's novel 1916 [*The Home and the World*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Home_and_the_World) consists of chapters told from the point of view of varying characters.
One of these is Sandip, who is a militant nationalist and an active participant in the [Swadeshi movement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swadeshi_movement).
In the third chapter, which is narrated from Sandip's point of view, there is a discussion between Nikhil's old tutor Chandranath and Sandip.
(Nikhil is one of the novel's main characters and refuses to take part in Swadeshi.)
The passage that is relevant to this question is the following (emphasis mine):

> Chandranath Babu began to talk about Swadeshi. I thought I would let him go on with his monologues. There is nothing like letting an old man talk himself out. It makes him feel that he is winding up the world, forgetting all the while how far away the real world is from his wagging tongue.
> But even my worst enemy would not accuse me of patience. And when Chandranath Babu went on to say: "If we expect to gather fruit where we have sown no seed, then we . . ." I had to interrupt him.
> "**Who wants fruit?**" I cried. "**We go by the Author of the Gita who says that we are concerned only with the doing, not with the fruit of our deeds.**"

The Gita is obviously the [*Bhagavad Gita*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhagavad_Gita), which is attributed to Vyasa.
According to the [chapter summaries on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhagavad_Gita#Chapters), Sandip is most likely alluding to something from Chapter 3.
Is this correct and what are the exact lines that Sandip is alluding to?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### tl;dr

[*Bhagavad Geeta* 2:47](https://www.bhagavad-gita.us/bhagavad-gita-2-47/)

### Source of Sandip's allusion

The passage Sandip alludes to is indeed from the *Bhagavad Geeta*. The exact source is Chapter 2, verse 47:

> कर्मण्येवाधिकारस्ते मा फलेषु कदाचन ।
> मा कर्मफलहेतुर्भूर्मा ते सङ्गोऽस्त्वकर्मणि ॥

[iTrans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITRANS):

> karmaNyevaadhikaaraste ma phaleShu kadaachana
> maa karmaphalaheturbhuurmaa te sa~Ngo.ostavakarmaNi

Translation (mine):

> You have control over action alone, none whatsoever over its fruits. Neither consider yourself the cause of the fruits of action, nor be attached to inaction.

The context of this, the best-known verse from the *Geeta*, is as follows: Arjuna, the most skilled warrior on one side of an epic battle, loses heart just before the battle begins. He finds himself ranged against his cousins, his gurus, and his elders. Since bonds of affection and gratitude bind him to them, he feels unable to take up arms as he is required to. He considers renouncing the battlefield. Arjuna's close friend Krishna, who has agreed to be his charioteer in the war, counsels him that since the war is just, participating is the only viable option. When Arjuna says that he does not want to cause the death of his kinsmen, and adds that winning the kingdom would not be worth that price, Krishna responds with this verse.

The word translated here as *control*, अधिकार / adhikaar, has a wide range of meaning that includes *authority* as well as *right* or *entitlement*. Arjuna should not see his actions as the *cause*, हेतु / hetu, of their outcome. Krishna counsels Arjuna that he must act responsibly, but without any expectation regarding the consequences. Action is within his control, so he is both entitled and obligated to act. However, he is not entitled to any specific results, nor are they within his control.

### The *Bhagavad Geeta* in the *Mahabharata*

While regularly treated as a stand-alone text, the *Bhagavad Geeta* is a small part of a much longer Sanskrit epic, the *Mahabharata*. It comprises chapters 23-40 of Book 6, the *[Book of Bhishma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhishma_Parva)*. The *Geeta* is considered a late interpolation into the epic. The [earliest written references](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahabharata#Accretion_and_redaction) to the *Mahabharata* date back to the 4th C BCE, with an oral tradition going back to the 8th or 9th C BCE. By contrast, the *Bhagavad Geeta* likely [dates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhagavad_Gita#Date) to the 2nd C BCE. In the context of the larger epic, the source of Sandip's allusion would be *Mahabharata* 06:24:47 rather than *Geeta* 2:47.

### Attributed Authorship of the *Geeta*

The question mentions that the *Geeta* is attributed to Vyasa. That is certainly true, in that the entire *Mahabharata* is considered Vyasa's. Nevertheless, as touched upon in an [answer to another question](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/16590/289) on this site, the *Mahabharata* is told through a series of narrative frames. The action on the battlefield is related in real time to the blind king [Dhritarashtra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dhritarashtra) by his charioteer [Sanjaya](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sanjaya), whom the gods have granted divine sight so that he can see the entire battle in real time. Putting this together with the overall narrative frame of the *Mahabharata*, what we read is:

- a text that represents what
- Ugrashravas said to Shaunaka, that
- Vaishampayan said to Ugrashravas, that
- Vyasa said to Vaishampayan, that
- Sanjaya said to Dhritarashtra that
- Krishna said to Arjuna.

These narrative frames notwithstanding, a good Hindu would attribute the *Bhagavad Geeta* to Krishna rather than Vyasa. The *Bhagavad Geeta* literally translates to *The Song of God*. Sanjaya uses direct speech to narrate Krishna's words to Dhritarashtra. So the chief speaker of the *Geeta* is Krishna, with Arjuna and Sanjaya getting some words in edgewise. Krishna's speeches are marked with श्रीभगवानुवाच / shriibhagavaanuvaacha, "the Lord God says".

Nikhil's challenge to Chandranath is therefore pretty audacious, relying as it does on the words of God himself.

### Note on Transliteration

The first vowel in *Geeta* is a long [ i ]. [IAST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Alphabet_of_Sanskrit_Transliteration) convention would represent गीता as *Gītā*. Strict [iTrans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ITRANS) would represent it as *giitaa*. Since IAST is hard to type on an ASCII keyboard, and iTrans specifically designed for such a keyboard, I tend to use the latter. Unlike IAST, however, iTrans is case-sensitive; G and g represent two different sounds. This makes it awkward to use for titles when capitalization would ordinarily be desirable. *Geeta* is probably the most common conventional, if nonstandard, transliteration of गीता, and I've defaulted to that for the title. The same is true for proper names: Krishna is conventional and nonstandard; IAST would be kṛṣṇa (or Kṛṣṇa); iTrans, kR^iShNa. Direct quotations from the text use iTrans.