# Is the Ramayana contained in the Mahabharata?

Tags: intertextuality, mahabharata, sanskrit-language, ramayana

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahabharata) says:

> Among the principal works and stories in the Mahābhārata are the Bhagavad Gita, the story of Damayanti, the story of Savitri and Satyavan, the story of Kacha and Devyani, the story of Ṛṣyasringa and an abbreviated version of the Rāmāyaṇa, often considered as works in their own right.

I know that the [Bhagavad Gita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bhagavad_Gita) is often treated as a separate text, not just an integral part of the Mahabharata, but the [Ramayana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramayana), as far as I know, really is a different piece of Sanskrit epic poetry, separate from the Mahabharata. The same Wikipedia page quoted above even mentions them as "the two major Sanskrit epics of ancient India". Then in what sense can the Ramayana be seen as "in" the Mahabharata? Is it retold within the Mahabharata, or has it sometimes been published as part of the Mahabharata, or what? (I would've guessed this might be Wikipedia talking nonsense again, but this is a fairly prominent claim, near the top of an article about a very well-known piece of literature, so surely it would've been spotted and corrected by now if it was mistaken.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### tl;dr

A section of the *Mahābhārata* narrates the story of Rāma. This section, called the *Rāmopākhyāna*, is far shorter than the *Rāmāyaṇa* which, as you correctly note, is a different epic altogether. The story as told in the *Ramopākhyāna*  also differs in some details from the *Rāmāyaṇa*. The exact textual relationship between Valmiki's *Rāmāyaṇa* and the *Rāmopākhyāna* is not settled. The latter could perhaps be "an abbreviated version of the *Rāmāyaṇa*," for some definition of "version."

### The Story of Rāma in the *Mahābhārata*

Book 3 of the *Mahābhārata* covers a period when the epic's heroes, the Pāṇḍavas, are exiled to the forest. The book is thus called the Āraṇyaka Parva or the Book of the Forest. Lamenting his plight, Yudhiṣṭhira, the eldest Pāṇḍava, asks the hermit Mārkaṇḍeya:

> अस्ति नूनं मया कश्चिदल्पभाग्यतरो नरः
> भवता दृष्टपूर्वो वा श्रुतपूर्वोऽपि वा भवेत्       ([3.257.10a–10c](https://bombay.indology.info/mahabharata/text/UD/MBh03.txt))
>
> asti nūnaṃ mayā kaścidalpabhāgyataro naraḥ
> bhavatā dṛṣṭapūrvo vā śrutapūrvo'pi vā bhavet
>
> Is there any man less fortunate than I that you have seen or heard of earlier?

Mārkaṇḍeya responds with a quick summary of the story of Rāma:

> प्राप्तमप्रतिमं दुःखं रामेण भरतर्षभ
> रक्षसा जानकी तस्य हृता भार्या बलीयसा
> आश्रमाद्राक्षसेन्द्रेण रावणेन विहायसा
> मायामास्थाय तरसा हत्वा गृध्रं जटायुषम्
> प्रत्याजहार तां रामः सुग्रीवबलमाश्रितः
> बद्ध्वा सेतुं समुद्रस्य दग्ध्वा लङ्कां शितैः शरैः       ([3.258.1a–3c](https://bombay.indology.info/mahabharata/text/UD/MBh03.txt))
>
> prāptamapratimaṃ duḥkhaṃ rāmeṇa bharatarṣabha
> rakṣasā jānakī tasya hṛtā bhāryā balīyasā
> āśramādrākṣasendreṇa rāvaṇena vihāyasā
> māyāmāsthāya tarasā hatvā gṛdhraṃ jaṭāyuṣam
> pratyājahāra tāṃ rāmaḥ sugrīvabalamāśritaḥ
> baddhvā setuṃ samudrasya dagdhvā laṅkāṃ śitaiḥ śaraiḥ
>
> Rāma underwent unmatched sorrow, O bull among the Bharatas! His wife Jānaki was seized by a mighty demon. Rāvaṇa, king of the demons, took her away from the hermitage through the skies, deceitfully, swiftly, having slain the vulture Jaṭāyu. Then Rāma, with the help of the powerful Sugrīva, rescued her after building a bridge across the sea and destroying Lanka with his sharp arrows.

Yudhiṣṭhira asks for details and Mārkaṇḍeya obliges with a longer version of Rāma's story.

This section of the *Mahābhārata*, called the [*Rāmopākhyāna*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramopakhyana) or "the Tale of Rāma," comprises chapters 257–275 of the Āraṇyaka Parva and totals 704 verses or just above 1400 lines. While reasonably long in itself, the *Rāmopākhyāna* is rather brief compared to the 24,000 verses of the *Rāmāyaṇa*. Like the *Bhagavad Gītā*, the *Ramopākhyāna* is self-contained, but unlike the former, it has never been in wide circulation as a stand-alone text, perhaps because the story is told in such greater detail in the *Rāmāyaṇa*. Vernacular retellings of Rāma's story are also considerably longer than the *Rāmopākhyāna*. For example, [Tulsidas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tulsidas)'s [Rāmacharitamānas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramcharitmanas), the best-known Hindi retelling of Rāma's story, is 10,902 verses long; [Kamban](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kambar_(poet))'s Tamil version, the [Rāmāvatāram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramavataram), is approximately 12,000 verses long.

### Is the *Rāmopākhyāna* an Abbreviated *Rāmāyaṇa*?

The story of Rāma circulates as myth and as such [exists in being retold](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/16590/289). The *Rāmāyaṇa* is the longest and most celebrated of these retellings. But other retellings such as Tulsidas's or Kamban's, or even the *Rāmopākhyāna*, do not merely summarize or abridge that epic. They are different versions of the story.

This can be demonstrated by noticing how some of the details of the *Rāmopākhyāna* are different from those in the *Rāmāyaṇa*. For example, the parentage of Rāvaṇa and his half-brother Kubera varies between the two texts. Also, in the *Rāmāyaṇa*, Rāma kills Rāvaṇa's brother Kumbhakarṇa, whereas in the *Rāmopākhyāna* the killer is Rāma's brother Lakṣmaṇa. Such variances suggest that the *Rāmopākhyāna* is something other than a simple summary of the *Rāmāyaṇa*.

There is, however, a tendency in popular culture to conflate all stories about Rāma with the *Rāmāyaṇa*. The *Rāmāyaṇa* and the *Mahābhārata* are considered holy books, and many if not most Hindus treat the stories they tell as literally true. Consequently, academic distinctions are moot. A scholarly question such as "How old is the *Mahābhārata*?" gets treated as an historical one: "When did the events described in the *Mahābhārata* take place?" And a textual question like “Is the *Rāmāyaṇa* a part of the *Mahābhārata* in the same way that the *Bhagavad Gītā* is?" is not distinguished from the very different question, "Does the *Mahābhārata* tell the story of Rāma?" The answer to the former is no; to the latter, yes.

### Scholarly Considerations about Dating and Textual Recensions

The presence of the story of Rāma in the *Mahābhārata* raises a question of textual scholarship: "Is the text of the *Rāmopākhyāna* related to the text of the *Rāmāyaṇa* as we have it?" That is to say, can we relate the two texts in a way that demonstrates conclusively whether or how either one is based on the other?

This is difficult to answer with any certainty. Both the *Rāmāyaṇa* and the *Mahābhārata* were [compiled over several overlapping centuries](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/35056). Being about four times longer than the *Rāmāyaṇa*, the *Mahābhārata* took longer to be compiled as well. Several facts conspire to muddy the waters:

- The earliest versions of the *Mahābhārata* story probably predate the earliest versions of the *Rāmāyaṇa*, but the text as we currently have it is later than the current text of the *Rāmāyaṇa*.
- The *Rāmāyaṇa* is set some centuries prior to the *Mahābhārata*. This makes sense, given that Mārkaṇḍeya tells Rāma's story in the latter.
- Yet the *Rāmāyaṇa* includes details about [the diffusion of Indo-Aryan culture over a wider geographic span](https://www.reddit.com/r/AskHistorians/comments/29av5n/which_epic_was_written_first_R%C4%81m%C4%81ya%E1%B9%87a_or/) than the *Mahābhārata* does; that suggests a later composition period than that of the *Mahābhārata*.
- Both epics have come down to us in several different manuscript versions grouped under [two](https://www.jstor.org/stable/41692082) major [recensions](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/24329), the Northern and the Southern. The various mss. of the *Rāmāyaṇa* in particular vary quite widely from each other.

Due to the complex textual history of both epics, it is very hard to state authoritatively whether or not the *Rāmopākhyāna* derives directly from the *Rāmāyaṇa*. Verbal echoes between the two texts abound, however. The repetition of exact phrases implies that the two are not independent works, but related in some way. Richard Lariviere, following the scholar Albrecht Weber, [lists four possibilities](https://www.jstor.org/stable/602865):

1. The *Rāmopākhyāna* is the source for the *Rāmāyaṇa*
2. It summarizes an early version the *Rāmāyaṇa*
3. It derives from the *Rāmāyaṇa*, with the compiler of the *Mahābhārata* making changes to suit his own purposes
4. The two stories are independently derived from a prior, unknown source.

Lariviere himself leans toward the third possibility. As Gareth McCaughan says in his [answer](https://literature.stackexchange.com/a/18530/289), this view is now the most widely held; scholarly opinion tends toward the belief that the *Rāmopākhyāna* is a memorial reconstruction of some version of the northern recension of the *Rāmāyaṇa*, though it cannot be definitively linked to any extant text of that recension. (I obviously have no ability to judge the scholarship on the textual history of the *Rāmopākhyāna* as it relates to the *Rāmāyaṇa*; nevertheless, it seems worth noting that at least in the field of Shakespearean textual scholarship, it is a matter of dispute whether [memorial reconstruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memorial_reconstruction) can be considered a viable explanation for textual variations.)

### Conclusion

The *Mahābhārata* posits itself as a repository of every story, every adage, every character, every situation, and every human reality:

> यदिहास्ति तदन्यत्र यन्नेहास्ति न तत्क्वचित्       ([1.56.33c](https://bombay.indology.info/mahabharata/text/UD/MBh01.txt))
>
> yadihāsti tadanyatra yannehāsti na tatkvacit
>
> The things within this may be found elsewhere; those not herein are found nowhere.

The story of Rāma is indeed found in this encyclopedic work, but to claim that the entirety of the *Rāmāyaṇa* is therefore contained within the text of the *Mahābhārata* would be mistaken.

### Notes

1. The proper names of the poets Valmiki, Tulsidas, and Kamban are not transliterated. Otherwise, Sanskrit quotations, words, and names are transliterated using [IAST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Alphabet_of_Sanskrit_Transliteration).
2. Translations from the Sanskrit are my own and I am not qualified to translate Sanskrit. So YMMV, AYOR, etc.

Answer (score 9):

The Mahabharata does not contain the Ramayana (an epic work 24000 verses long). It does, however, contain the so-called [Ramopakhyana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramopakhyana) which (like the Ramayana) tells the story of Rama and Sita but (unlike the Ramayana) is only about 700 verses long. This is the "abbreviated version of the Ramayana" referred to in the Wikipedia article on the Mahabharata.

The Ramopakhyana obviously contains much less material than the Ramayana, and it differs in other ways; for instance, in the Ramayana Rama is an avatar of Vishnu, but in the Ramopakhyana he is an ordinary human being. [EDITED to add:] ... At least, that's what I had read, but in comments below user *also ran* points out a place near the beginning where it does seem to be being stated that Rama is an incarnation of Vishnu, so it seems this isn't so clear-cut a difference.

The Wikipedia page I linked above quotes one W J Johnson as saying that "most current scholarship believes [the Ramopakhyana] to have been derived from a memorized version of the story drawn from the northern recension of the Rāmāyaṇa prior to the completion of that text as we now have it". If this is so, then there is a family relationship between what's in the Mahabharata and the Ramayana itself, but it's certainly not at all true that the Mahabharata contains the Ramayana.

Comment: Nice answer. It might be worth mentioning that the portions of the *Rāmāyaṇa* that refer to Rāma as an avatar of Vishṇu are considered later interpolations.

Comment: Even in the Ramopakhyana of the Mahabharata, Rama is considered as an incarnation of Vishnu.

Comment: Really? Then I am misinformed. I read through the text (in English translation, and fairly quickly, so I could certainly have missed things) and I see him called a "bull among men" and a "tiger among men" and a "hero" and so forth, and after his defeat of Ravana he has a lot of nice things said about him by gods -- but I don't see anything suggesting he's an avatar of Vishnu. What have I missed?

Comment: Plz check - https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m03/m03274.htm   Brahma said, 'O Agni, he cannot be conquered in battle by either the gods or the Asuras! I have already ordained that which is needful for that purpose. Indeed his death is near! Urged by me, the four-handed (not headed) God hath already been incarnate for that object. Even **Vishnu** that foremost of smiters will achieve that object!'

Comment: From the same link - And beget ye on monkeys and bears, heroic sons possessed of great strength and capable of assuming any form at will as **allies of Vishnu!'**

Comment: Anticipating this question - yes, both instances are present in BORI critical edition of Mahabharata (chapter 260, verses 5 and 7 in below link)- https://sanskritdocuments.org/mirrors/mahabharata/txt/mbh03.itx

Comment: Hmm, looks pretty convincing. My apologies. (It does seem curious -- though I'm not familiar enough with the general conventions of ancient Indian epics for it to matter much how it seems to me -- that that's just dropped in there while everything else said about Rama in the Ramopakhyana treats him as an ordinary human being, albeit an extraordinary ordinary human being.)